# prettyplotlib labels and annotations are off-centred

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, prettyplotlib

**Why are annotations of `prettyplotlib` barchat and x-axis labels off-centered?**

Using `prettyplotlib==0.1.7`

If we create a normal barchart with the x-axis as defined by the 2nd argument, the labels are well centred on the bar:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import prettyplotlib as ppl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

counter = {1:1, 2:4, 3:9, 4:16, 5:25, 6:36, 7:49}

x, y = zip(*counter.items())

ppl.bar(ax, x , y, grid='y')
```

[out]:

[image]

But if we use the `xticklabels` the x-axis labels goes off-center:

```
ppl.bar(ax, x , y, xticklabels=list('1234567'), grid='y')
```

[out]:

[image]

Similarly, when we use the `annotate=True` argument, it goes off-center:

```
ppl.bar(ax, x , y, annotate=True, grid='y')
```

[out]:

[image]

It's unlike the examples shown on https://github.com/olgabot/prettyplotlib/wiki/Examples-with-code#hist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not using prettyplotlib any more. It's 3 years old and all it's basically doing is to change the style of the plots. Better use matplotlib directly and if you are not happy with the style, use [a different one](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html) or [create your own](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html). If you encounter problems, questions about changing the style also have a very high chance of being answered here.

Here is a way how to change the style to recreate the plot from the above question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

style = {"axes.grid" : True,
         "axes.grid.axis" : "y",
         "axes.spines.top"  : False,
         "axes.spines.right"  : False,
         "grid.color" : "white",
         "ytick.left" : False,
         "xtick.bottom" : False,
         }
plt.rcParams.update(style)

counter = {1:1, 2:4, 3:9, 4:16, 5:25, 6:36, 7:49}
x, y = zip(*counter.items())

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.bar(x , y, color="#66c2a5" )

plt.show()
```

[image]

Now you are  free to set different xticklabels,

```
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(list("ABCDEFG"))
```

Or annotate the the bars,

```
for i,j in zip(x,y):
    ax.annotate(str(j), xy=(i,j), xytext=(0, 4),textcoords='offset points',ha="center")
```

[image]

The matplotlib documentation is pretty well maintained and there are lots of question here to help you do your special case plots if ever needed.

Comment: Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest ! I've moved to `seaborn` + `matplotlib`.